# Efficiently calculating pairwise intersection between cell array elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cell-array

Suppose you have 2 cell arrays:

tri1 (4x1 cell)

```
[1; 3; 4]
[2; 4]
[1; 2; 3]
[1; 3; 4]
```

and tri2 (4x1 cell)

```
[1; 2; 3]
[1; 2; 3]
[1; 3; 4]
[2; 4]
```

and you want to calculate the intersection between each 2 corresponding cell elements. In this example, the result would be something like this:

tri12 (4x1 cell)

```
[1; 3]
2
[1; 3]
4
```

**Currently** I calculate this intersection using *cellfun* like this:

```
tri12 = cellfun(@(t1, t2){intersect(t1, t2)}, tri1, tri2);
```

However, this is extremely slow when the cell arrays are large.

**My question**, is there a faster way to calculate the same intersection result without having to use *cellfun*?

**Please note** that there is no need to maintain the exact current format of the involved objects (i.e. being cell arrays). So any fast solution that would compute the same result is perfectly fine.

Comment: As a starting point for comparison, have you tried looping through the cell arrays explicitly?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't try looping. However, I think it wouldn't make much difference. I read somewhere that cellfun is slower than looping and not much slower. I will try looping but a loopless solution would be much better.

Comment: The advantage between loops and `cellfun` has swung back and forth so many times over the years I've lost track of which is faster in some situations. Doesn't hurt to try. I'm sure someone will come along with another solution, I don't have anything in mind at the moment.

Comment: Are the numbers in the sets integers within some range? (eg. in above, they are integers indexed from 1 to 4)

Comment: @MatthewGunn: That's a good question. Maybe the sets could be described using a logical matrix, e.g. `tri1=[1 0 1 1;0 1 0 1;1 1 1 0;1 0 1 1]`, then intersecting is just an `and` operation.

Comment: @Daniel You perfectly anticipated where I was going :)

Answer (score 2):

Building upon Matthew Gunn solution which I find elegant, in the case of bounded non-negative integers, where the upper bound is relatively large still, and when the cells are very large.

We can basically apply this to each pair of cell elements, while preallocating a long row of logicals which can be reused for each pair, taking care about cleaning it up each time. This would look like:

```
function C1_C2 = fast_intersect( C1, C2, max_int )

    x = false(1,max_int);
    y = false(1,max_int);

    C1_C2 = cellfun( @fast_intersect_impl, C1, C2, 'UniformOutput', false );


    function ab = fast_intersect_impl(a,b)

        x(a)=true; y(b)=true;
        ab = find(x & y);
        x(a)=false; y(b)=false;

    end

end
```

Comment: I've got work to do, but I'm a bit curious how fast the different methods are. If none of these work and performance is critical, the way to go is probably to write a mex function using STL C++ libraries: for each pair of vectors representing sets in the cell array, load up two STL sets and calculate the intersection. You could avoid a call to cellfun entirely.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Set intersections in C++ is a bit clunky, it would be faster and simpler to go with C and a single row of `char` bins. For each pair or arrays, iterate on first array setting the bins, iterate on the second array checking for already set bins, iterate on first array again to unset bins.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn thanks for the suggestion. I did a little bit of profiling. I will add another comment because it seems that SO doesn't allowing including 2 @'s in the same comment and MatthewGun wanted to know about the difference

Comment: @MatthewGunn profiling the difference between the 2 methods, there is a bit of an enhancement. The average time to compute the intersection between 2 cell arrays each one containing 58806 elements: the average is 6 secs vs. 9 secs.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers in your sets are integers indexed from 1 to some not so huge element, you could represent the sets in a matrix using columns as indicators. (i.e. X(i,j) is a binary indicator as to whether element j is in set i.) Load up the matrices with:

```
X = false(length(tri1), MAXELEMENT);
for i=1:length(tri1), 
  X(i,tri1{i}') = true; 
end
Y = false(length(tri2), MAXELEMENT);
for i=1:length(tri2), 
  Y(i,tri2{i}') = true; 
end
```

Then the intersection is just `myintersection = X & Y;` which should be super fast.

Comment: I like the idea, it is similar to bin counting that I suggested, however I doubt it is a practical solution if he is complaining about `cellfun` being slow, the problem being that I expect the cells to be very long. Forming the matrix then, together with a possibly large upper bound, might cause memory problems.

Comment: Using logical arrays to represents sets lives or dies on the number of elements that could be in the set.

If he has 1 million sets of items 1 through 4, the logical array will crush it. If he has 1 million sets of 5 numbers from 1 to 1 billion, logical arrays obviously will not work.

Comment: See an extension of your idea using `cellfun` when the cells and bound are both large.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any improvement to your solution. However, are you sure you didn't mean to write

```
tri12 = cellfun( @(t1, t2) intersect(t1, t2), tri1, tri2, 'UniformOutput', false );
```

instead? That is, returning an array, and not a cell array for each couple? This could speed things up a little.

`intersect` uses `unique` under the hood for numeric arrays, which is as good as it gets without further constraints. However, if you know the values in your arrays are all positive integers bounded by a relatively small value (say under tens of millions), you might be able to cook an *ad hoc* solution in `C/Mex` using bin counts. The Matlab equivalent would be using `accumarray`, but I doubt that would be faster than `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a script](https://github.com/brianpenghe/Matlab-genomics/blob/master/MetaIntersect.m) to do pairwise intersection.

You will need to convert the cells to rectangle tables first and then do MetaIntersect(A,B)